# multiple rows into columns mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am trying to create a mysql query that will convert multiple rows in a table to unique columns

The data I have is as follows:

[image: DB table]

The table I would like to see is as follows:

```
GEID|Username|First Name|Last Name|Email|Country|Dealer Code
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement which could be used is

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value 1 , column 2 = value 2 ...
Where condition;
```

Sorry but my SQL isn't the best but hope the statement helps

Answer (score 0):

This is a real pain, because you don't have an id identifying groups that are the same.  In other words, you are missing the entity id.

I think you can construct one by counting the number of `GEID` values before any given row.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
select max(case when fieldname = 'GEID' then fieldData end) as GEID,
       max(case when fieldname = 'Username' then fieldData end) as Username,
       . . .
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.id <= t.id and t2.fieldName = 'GEID'
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp;
```